# Using classic asp classes in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

My older app has classes written in classic asp. Just wondering, how can I use class created with classic asp in aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred approach is to rewrite the code in a .NET language, but if you want to try something kinda crazy instead, you can:

First, convert the ASP class to a [Microsoft Windows Script Component](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224980) (known as a Scriptlet).

Then try [calling it as a COM component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx) from your .NET app.

But, really, the work you put into that is better spent doing a rewrite, for a multitude of reasons.